# Wrapping jquery mobile in app setup

Tags: jquery-mobile, push-notification

I am testing some cross platform development tools to develop a mobile application.
my needs from the system (device) is really low.

1. The application needs live in the background (as a service) always.
2. I need to push notifications to the device 
   like:

   [image]

I want to support android and ios phones and tablets.

Is there any tool that can wrap my jquery mobile and give me an api for the notifications?

Thanks